# HP Proliant DL380 Gen9 - - Logical Drive 1 has failed Re-enable failed logical

Tags: hp-smart-array, hpe

I have a HP Proliant DL360 Gen9 Server, everything working fine. but suddenly server is not bootable, booting time we got three errors.
listed below.

1. 313-HP smart storage battery 1 failure - Battery shutdown event code: 0x0400.
   2.Embedded Storage : Dynamic Smart Array B140i - SATA Optical Drive 1 - Configuration Required 
   3.Embedded RAID : Smart Array  P440ar controller - Configuration Required - 1779-slot 0 drive array - replacement drive(s) detected OR previously failed drives now appear to be operational....etc
   Actions we taken:
2. 1st i thought smart storage battery 1 failure, i confirmed with ILO interface then i replaced with new battery, then ILO interface i checked its ok.
3. for this issue ( Embedded Storage : Dynamic Smart Array B140i - SATA Optical Drive 1 - Configuration Required ) i did this
   https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c04655546

Image 1: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1i55hYa6o1jeAZKcaf9mkE4Dwu1bWOzlM

after i did above actions,

when booting time 3rd issue was still exits.

now i went to smart storage administrator i checked controllers.

Image 2 : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SLJzGKDuf2v2l7Oxsi5nmCxGMt44_g54

It saying Logical drive status failed,

where option is available Re-enable failed logical drive.

Now my question if i re enable failed logical drive my data will available or not.

Please guide me guys,

I have Backup of server but last two days backup not taken.

Server have 600GB  5 SAS HDD with Raid 5.